# How to get Socket Id in Socket.io on Android?

Tags: android, sockets

I want to get the id of my socket running in Android. Everything is create normally and is able to send data back and forth but I need to get the Androids socket id for usage throughout the entire application. I have tried to find a solution but either they were outdated or does not work. Below is my latest attempt at solving this issue. With this attempt it errors saying that there are no elements in `args[0]`. I have also tried `mSocket.id();` but that returns nothing.

```
public class GameSocket {
private Socket mSocket = null;

private static GameSocket mInstance;
public synchronized static GameSocket getInstance() {
     if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new GameSocket();
     }
     return mInstance;
}

public void initialize() {
     mSocket = IO.socket(URI.create(SERVER_URI));
     mSocket.off();
     mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
           Log.d(GameSocket.class.getSimpleName(), "Event connection...");
           mSocketId = args[0].toString();
           Log.d("CONNECT ID", mSocketId);
        }
     })
     .on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
         @Override
         public void call(Object... args) {
            if (args != null) {
               Log.e(GameSocket.class.getSimpleName(), "Socket Event Error: " + args[0].toString());
            }
         }
     });
 }
}
```